# Pool tables in Shiny app - efficient loading

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, mariadb, pool

What's the best way to improve the efficiency of loading several tables from a MySQL (Maria) DB into R Shiny using the [pool package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pool/pool.pdf)?

At the moment I'm using a for loop. Should I initialise the tables or is there a better way (an apply function)?

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv      = RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
  dbname   = "db",
  host     = "localhost",
  username = "user", 
  password = "",
  port     = 3306,
  bigint   = "numeric"
)
tabFull <- dbListTables(pool)
tablesExport <- tabFull[grepl("export", tabFull)]

  for(i in 1:length(tablesExport)){
     tmp <- data.frame(tbl(pool, tablesExport[i]))
     tmp$exclDate <- tmp$uploaded_at + (365*24*60*60)  
     tmp <- filter(tmp, !(exclDate > Sys.time() & !(private %in% c(0, NA))) & excluded %in% c(0, NA)) 
     assign(tablesExport[i], select(tmp, -exclDate, -excluded, -export_time, -private)

     #assign(tablesExport[i], `[[<-`(get(tablesExport[i]), 'exclDate', value = as.POSIXct(eval(parse(text = tablesExport[i]))$uploaded_at) + (365*24*60*60)))
     #assign(tablesExport[i], filter(eval(parse(text = tablesExport[i])), !(exclDate > Sys.time() & !(private %in% c(0, NA))) & excluded %in% c(0, NA)))
     #assign(tablesExport[i], select(eval(parse(text = tablesExport[i])), -exclDate, -excluded, -export_time, -private))
  }
```

A reprex is difficult when there's a DB involved so I hope this pseudo code will do. All code is up on github too, so if you need more context see [here for shiny](https://github.com/ilri/feast-data-shiny/blob/main/Download/server.R) and [here for the sql](https://github.com/ilri/feast-data-web/tree/master/sql).

Comment: Wow, !@! BINGO !@!. I don't know that I've seen code -- in one line, even -- that combines `assign`, `get`, `eval`, and `parse` (all *high-risk* functions), and `\`[[<-\`` (which is fine, but primarily good for code-golf and/or obfuscated code). The first four functions I listed are all that I generally *strongly discourage using*, and you've combined them into one line. I'm guessing you have reason for it, but ... *dang* ...

Comment: Perhaps less poignantly ... I don't think minimizing R code is going to have significant performance improvements, so if your use of everything-on-one-line is for run-time, then I suggest that *readability* is hand-in-hand with *maintainability*, which means that in the long term it'll be easier to update or troubleshoot. Also, you `assign` to the same `tablesExport[i]` four times each pass; it would be far better (and more readable :-) to work with a temporary variable in the `for` loop, and if you really need `assign`, do it *once* at the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: To answer your questions: the only `apply` function I'd recommend is `lapply`, in line with https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 (storing a `list`-of-`data.frame`s, a strong alternative to using `get`/`assign`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @r2evans. Not the best bingo win, but it worked for a start. Now time to make some improvements. All ears

Comment: @r2evans I'm playing along at home and started to make edits based on your comments

Comment: See my answers ... lots of stylistic projection, my apologies, take it all with a grain of salt. It is true, though, that general best practices in robust/resilient R code discourages the use of all four of those functions, sparing very specific exceptional situations. Even then, they are still risky.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you write one function that does all of which you have in your `for` loop and iterate over a list of tables more simply (at least more readable).

I think I understand your motivation for working in side-effect, assigning each table to its own variable, so I'll stick with that (but offer an alternative anyway). I'll also stick with your use of `dplyr` verbs and just go all-in with pipes (for readability).

```r
library(dplyr)
func <- function(tblnm, con, envir = NULL) {
  now <- Sys.time()
  yearseconds <- (365*24*60*60)
  dat <- data.frame(tbl(con, tblnm)) %>%
    mutate(exclDate = uploaded_at + yearseconds) %>%
    filter(!(exclDate > now & !(private %in% c(0, NA))) & excluded %in% c(0, NA)) %>%
    select(-exclDate, -excluded, -export_time, -private)
  if (!is.null(envir)) assign(tblnm, dat, envir = envir)
  invisible(dat)
}
```

With this, you can replace much of above with

```r
for (i in seq_along(tablesExport)) {
  func(tablesExport[i], con = pool, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Note that I was explicit about passing both the connection object (your `pool`) and the `envir`onment in which you wanted the side-effect. I did this to be more declarative, as well as supporting perhaps other uses (within non-global environments, who knows).

One thing that that supports is operating without side-effect, working with a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) that I mentioned in my comment. Instead of the `for` loop and assigning each table to its own variable, you can then do:

```r
dat <- lapply(setNames(nm=tablesExport), func, con = pool, envir = NULL)
```

The `envir=NULL` is not strictly needed because the default in the function definition is that, but I did it here to be perfectly clear: I don't want side-effect. Using this `dat`, you would then use `dat[[ tableExports[3] ]]` or (if one table is named `UserList`) `dat$UserList` to access individual tables.

A couple of notes about some of my style choices:

- I try to not use `1:length(...)`; while it works more of the time, if `length(.)` is ever `0`, one would hope that the `for` loop will do nothing, but unfortunately it sees `1:0` which resolves to `c(1, 0)`, not an empty vector. `seq_along(x)` is equivalent to `seq_len(length(x))` is equivalent to `1:length(x)` *except* when `x` is empty.
- I used `lapply(setNames(nm=tablesExports),...)` since the default action of `lapply` is to name its elements on output only if the object is named going in. While `sapply` *does* name things intuitively (it substitutes/deparses the vector/list), it can also return a vector or a list, which can be frustrating for pure programmatic use. I prefer `lapply` for that reason. Alternatively, I could have used `sapply(tableExports, func, con=pool, envir=NULL, USE.NAMES=FALSE)` for the same effect.
- I defined `now` and `yearseconds` mostly because I try to resist hard-coded constants in code without clear definition. Naming them something meaningful is useful and declarative. (I've had to debug modules that used for instance `10` in various places throughout the code ... some of them meant the same constant, some meant something different, so a global-search-replace to update one of the constants failed.)
- I used `invisible` for the option of using it with side-effect; without `invisible`, then `func(somename,...)` would dump a frame to the console, which may not be what you want. `invisible` allows you to `return` a value, but if the user does not explicitly capture it into an object, then don't pummel the console with a frame rendering. When used as `somevar <- func(...)`, it does absolutely nothing.
- One last thing ... a more defensive version of `func` would check for the existence of those column names before arbitrarily filtering on them. One would then either (a) fail immediately, or (b) only filter on a column if the column is present. While (b) could still produce "interesting" effects in down-stream code, it would still allow the down-stream code to execute.

Comment: Great answer. I appreciate the style explanations too. 1:seq_len(length(x))  is filling all my for loops now.
P.S. Do you have any links to the perils of assign, eval, parse and get?

Comment: On your P.S., not authoritative links, mostly just experience here on StackOverflow and in the wild in my day job with other R programmers. If you read enough questions on SO that ask about using `eval`/`parse`, you'll find lots of warnings including inadvertent code-injection (similar to sql injection, even when not malicious). And usually, the desire to use `assign`/`get` are predicated on an architecture that has not considered long-term effects and things like ease of troubleshooting. Sorry, I should find a canonical reference to why those should be used sparingly ...

Comment: No problem. Just curious. Also curious about invisible(). Googling now ...

Comment: See my comment about `invisible`. Perhaps overkill for your use, I generalized the function a little based on multiple use-cases.

Comment: Doing some rough benchmarking (system.time) I get similar times. 

Func + lapply - 67.89, 67.29;

Func + for-loop - 68.16, 66.59;

Old - 67.297, 67.23.
I think I need to have a closer look at the pool package

Comment: If you're only doing a one-time query of all data from those tables, the `pool` package gets you very little; you may be able to go straight to the `odbc` package instead. The biggest benefit (to me) of the `pool` package is its auto-reconnect functionality, where when a connection dies (timeout, network glitch, who knows), it will attempt to reconnect the next time you try to use it; normal `DBI` connections (including `odbc`, `RPostgres`, etc) will just fail and make *you* do the reconnection. (`pool` should not be slowing you down, either.)